# How to change multiple div background color one click one circle div color change with one button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to making code one button click and multiple div change background color. but not found any solutions.
It should be one click 1 circle bgcolor will change, second click second circle background color will change, third click third circle color change like this. please help me.

```
my code HTML - 

<div class="main_area">
    <div class="circle1" id="bg1">1</div>
    <div class="circle1" id="bg2">2</div>
    <div class="circle1" id="bg3">3</div>
    <div class="circle1" id="bg4">4</div>
    <div class="circle1" id="bg5">5</div>
</div>
<div class="button_area"><button class="redBg" id="click">click Me</button></div>

css - 
<style>
        .circle1 {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .main_area {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }

        .button_area {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: 5rem;
        }
    </style>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // $('.redBg').click(function () {
            //  $('#bg1').css('background-color', 'red');
            // });

            // loop

            var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            console.log(arr);
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                $('.redBg').click(function () {
                    $('.circle1').css('background-color', 'red');
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
        .circle1 {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .main_area {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }

        .button_area {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: 5rem;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var count=1;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("circle1");
            x[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";


            //var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            //console.log(arr);
                $('.redBg').click(function () {
                    if(count==5)
                        count=0;
                    $('.circle1').css("backgroundColor","initial");
                   x[count++].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main_area">
    <div class="circle1" id="bg1">1</div>
    <div class="circle1" id="bg2">2</div>
    <div class="circle1" id="bg3">3</div>
    <div class="circle1" id="bg4">4</div>
    <div class="circle1" id="bg5">5</div>
</div>
<div class="button_area"><button class="redBg" id="click">click Me</button></div>


</body>
</html>
```

you have not included the jquery library in your header. add the below code to the header

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: just run the code snippet. i hope this is what you needed!!